# Does 3‐ethyl‐1,1‐dimethylcyclohexane have a stereocenter?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

I knew that we have a stereocenter if the carbon is bonded to four different groups.

According to the stereocenter rules, I should have $\ce{CH2}$ bonded to the carbon of the stereocenter (marked with asterisk), an ethyl and a hydrogen. How is it possible to have two equal groups? What did I do wrong?

[image: 3‐ethyl‐1,1‐dimethylcyclohexane]

Comment: I've redrawn the structure, assigned the compound's name omitting R/S notational part and slightly corrected the wording. Hopefully this is OK, but please do feel free to double-check so that the intended gist of a question is preserved.

Comment: @Amiga 500: The structure drawn by andselisk has its corresponding enantiomer. That means compound has a chiral carbon as indicated. Justifying it is your homework assignment.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne it's not a homework, the question is whether this molecule is a stereocenter or not. As I've drawn, there are three groups: Ch2 and Ch2 molecules, an ethyl, and the hydrogen. According to the rule,it  is a stereocenter if it has 4 groups. Which is the fourth group?

Comment: @Amiga500 The stereocenter in this molecule has four different branching: all atoms counterclockwise in this cyclohexane ring; all atoms clockwise in the cyclohexane ring; the hydrogen; and the ethyl. So it's not about just the one linked $\ce{CH2}$, but all the linked atoms. The mirror image of this molecule will not overlay on the above, but will be a different molecule.

Comment: @z1273 but we have two Ch2 molecules, so is it still a stereocenter? I mean, my question is: is the C atom linked to two different groups Ch2??

Comment: There's more than single $\ce{CH2}$s. When considering the ethyl, you didn't stop at the linked $\ce{CH2}$, but you included all of the linked atoms there, i.e. an additional $\ce{CH3}$. The same is true for the cyclic $\ce{CH2}$s. One has $\ce{CH2CH2CH2C(CH3)2CH2}$ and the other has $\ce{CH2C(CH3)2CH2CH2CH2}$ - they're different. The four substituents of the chiral center are different. As a result the mirror image of the whole molecule does not overlay the original molecule. That can be attributed to that one stereocenter.

Comment: Imagine to be the C and look around. Each time you are bearing along a bond you see 4 different landscape. H- ethyl- and the the rest of the cycle but from different not equivalent sides. In other words do not stop at the CH2....